# (CSS) How to use :not and :hover at the same time?

Tags: css, typescript

I want to stop showing hover while checkbox is checked, how can I do?

```
// Typescript
<label className={styles.checkbox_container}>
  <input type="checkbox" />This is a Label
  <span className={styles.checkmark}></span> // customized tick symbol with red color for checked status
  <span className={styles.checkmarkHover}></span> // customized tick symbol with blue color for :hover;
</label>  

// CSS 
.checkbox_container:not(.checkbox_container input:checked):hover input ~ .checkmarkHover {
    // does not work
}
```

When the checkbox is not being checked, hover works.
When the checkbox is being checked, hover expected to do nothing.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't look like TypeScript, but like HTML - but not vanilla. What framework(s) are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're applying `:not` to the wrong element. `.checkbox_container` will never match `.checkbox_container input:checked` anyway. You want `input:not(:checked)`.

```css
.checkbox_container:hover input:not(:checked) ~ .checkmarkHover
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox_container">
  <input type="checkbox" />This is a Label
  <span class="checkmark">XXX</span>
  <span class="checkmarkHover">YYY</span>
</label>
```

Comment: OH I used the wrong way, Thank you so much!